# Internationalization in Liferay

Tags: jsp, internationalization, liferay, liferay-6

How can I make internationalization using jstl? I've read a lot about fmt: taglib but I still don't get how to use it. For example, we have line

```
<p><a href="${StackOverFlow}" title='<liferay-ui:message key="hello-world" />'>Stack_over_flow</a></p>
```

And the Language.properties in the docroot/src/content folder. How can I use JSTL in the title section?

I read a lot about this issue but had no effect. @Shivam

Comment: Could you please be more clear with what you exactly need.Is the internationalization working for you otherwise or you want to specifically use <fmt> taglib.What errors are you getting?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I have no errors. I just have a task to refactor this line
`title='<liferay-ui:message key="hello-world" />'` using JSTL. I really don't know how do to it. I suppose I should use `<fmt...` but Im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, the answer was too easy:

```
<c:set var="message">
    <liferay-ui:message key="hello-world" />
</c:set>

<p><a href="${StackOverFlow}"title="${message}">Stack_over_flow</a></p>
```

It was all about avoiding "tag in tag in tag in tag" construction.

Comment: @Shivam, may be it will be intresting for ya.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for this `<fmt:message key="hello-world">`
Do not forget to include the taglib `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>`

Comment: So we can't do this without `' '` symbols using `${}` ?

Comment: Expression language is only used for fetching some attributes while in this case it is just a message key,which is a constant value,hence no expression language is needed(so not used)

Comment: should we add another code like `<fmt:bundles`... ? Because if we paste `<fmt:message key="hello-world">` instead of stack_over_flow we get '????hello-world?????' and not 'hi'.  In the Language.properties I have hello-world=hi, ofc.

Comment: <fmt:setBundle basename="class.path.to.resource.bundle"/><fmt:message key="hello-world"> provide full path of resource bundle i.e. default properties  file

Comment: So if I have file Language.properties in `docroot/WEB-INF/content/Language.properties` I should write this:

`<fmt:setBundle basename="docroot/WEB-INF/content/Language.properties"/> ` and replace that line with `<fmt:message key="hello-world"> `, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120687/discussion-between-alexandr-and-shivam-aggarwal).

Comment: could you give me your email, please. I have one question, but don't want to create new thread.